# #define TheVLM(x) VLM::Global()->x TheVLM(Run());

Tags: c++

What does this mean in C++:

```
#define TheVLM(x) VLM::Global()->x TheVLM(Run());
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you sure it's not on two lines, like :

```
#define TheVLM(x) VLM::Global()->x 
TheVLM(Run());
```

In that case, it's nothing specfic to C++, it is a standard use of Macro. The second line will generate the following call after macro substitution:

```
VLM::Global()->Run();
```

Comment: For a second I was like - recursion in macros?